Issues Sending Swipeable Carousel Messages via Twilio WhatsApp API
I’m trying to send an interactive WhatsApp carousel using Twilio, but instead of receiving the carousel as expected, I get two separate messages. One contains the image, and the other contains the targeted text.
Below is the code I’m using for sending the carousel message:
@app.route('/send_carousel', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def send_carousel():
    """
    Sends an interactive carousel message to the specified WhatsApp number.
    """
    try:
        interactive_message = {
            "type": "interactive",
            "interactive": {
                "type": "list",
                "header": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Featured Products"
                },
                "body": {
                    "text": "Choose a product to learn more."
                },
                "footer": {
                    "text": "Thank you for shopping with us!"
                },
                "action": {
                    "button": "View Details",
                    "sections": [
                        {
                            "title": "Products",
                            "rows": [
                                {
                                    "id": "product1",
                                    "title": "Profile Picture",
                                    "description": "Check out my profile picture."
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "product2",
                                    "title": "Second Item",
                                    "description": "Explore more awesome products."
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }

        message = client.messages.create(
            from_=from_whatsapp_number,
            to=to_whatsapp_number,
            interactive=interactive_message["interactive"]
        )

        logging.info(f"Sent Message SID: {message.sid}")

        return jsonify({
            "message": "Carousel sent successfully",
            "message_sid": message.sid
        }), 200

    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception("Exception during message sending")
        return jsonify({
            "error": "An exception occurred while sending message",
            "details": str(e)
        }), 500

This is the result that I'm getting
Result Image
And this is the final output image that I'm Expecting
Expected Output
The final output is a carousel where we can swipe right and interact with the buttons.
Despite using this setup, instead of a single carousel with interactive buttons, I receive two messages: one with an image and one with text.
Am I missing something in the template payload or configuration? Any insights on why the WhatsApp catalogue carousel isn't appearing correctly would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

I'm not sure what the issue is that you are describing here. In case the carousel is not shown correctly in the WhatsApp client, make sure the template is approved.

Once you created the template with the payload mentioned above, create an approval request.
curl -X POST 'https://content.twilio.com/v1/Content/HXxxx/ApprovalRequests/whatsapp' \                              
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \    
  -u $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN  \
  -d '{
  "name": "if-needed-insert-here",
  "category": "UTILITY"
}'


Verify if the request has been approved.
curl -X GET 'https://content.twilio.com/v1/Content/HX8xxx/ApprovalRequests' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -u $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN




Hello IObert,
I have made some adjustments to the question to improve clarity. Could you please review it and respond accordingly?

Thanks for the adjustment. This is the problem I suspected. It seems to me your template is not approved. Can you submit an approval request as mentioned above?
